How to set converter property on a connector level?
I need to use the following property:
value.converter.ignore.default.for.nullables=true

in my setup as it is mentioned here.
When I set it as an environment variable it all works fine:
CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_IGNORE_DEFAULT_FOR_NULLABLES: true

But, to my understanding, it's also possible to set it on the connector level and this is what I try:
{
    "name": "source-mysql-true-local",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "taxify-binlog-db",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "root",
        "database.password": "",
        "database.server.id": "184054",
        "database.server.name": "cdc_mysql_avro.local",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:29092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "cdc_dbhistory_mysql.local",
        "include.schema.changes": "true",
        "snapshot.mode": "schema_only",
        "decimal.handling.mode": "string",
        "database.exclude.list": "infra,test",
        "table.exclude.list": ".*_gho$,.*_ghc$",
        "max.queue.size": "24576",
        "max.batch.size": "6144",
        "sanitize.field.names": "true",
        "value.converter.ignore.default.for.nullables": "true" <-- HERE
    }
}

And it does not work. Am I doing something wrong or this is just impossible? The connector that I'm using is debezium-mysql, 1.9.7.Final.

In that case you need to use the property replace.null.with.default for the JSONConverter.
{
"name": "source-mysql-true-local",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "taxify-binlog-db",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "root",
    "database.password": "",
    "database.server.id": "184054",
    "database.server.name": "cdc_mysql_avro.local",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:29092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "cdc_dbhistory_mysql.local",
    "include.schema.changes": "true",
    "snapshot.mode": "schema_only",
    "decimal.handling.mode": "string",
    "database.exclude.list": "infra,test",
    "table.exclude.list": ".*_gho$,.*_ghc$",
    "max.queue.size": "24576",
    "max.batch.size": "6144",
    "sanitize.field.names": "true",
    "value.converter.replace.null.with.default": "false"
}

